# Don't understand CIRCUMFLEX use in this UNIX command ls -L | grep -v ^zip

Tags: regex, unix, grep

```
ls -L | grep -v ^zip
```

What i understand from this command is, it is doing a listing and piping the output to a grep command which performs grep on the received output file list to select any file with file name not containing text "zip" and any file with file name containing text "zip".

If this is correct, then it seems useless or counter productive. Am i wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-v` means "don't match", `^` is the beginning of a line:

```
$ cat in.txt                
foo
zip
bar
--zip
baz
 zip
qux
$ $ grep -v '^zip' < in.txt   
foo
bar
--zip
baz
 zip
qux
```

Answer (score 3):

> to select any file with file name not containing text "zip" and any file with file name containing text "zip"

I don't see how you got to that conclusion. `^zip` matches lines starting with `zip`, and `-v` negates the pattern.